# full functions/implicatins of wpautop?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

So I just removed wpautop from my wordpress site with the intention of removing all those pesky p tags it leaves around. But, after doing so by adding;

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

to my functions.php file, my whole site lost a lot of formatting and just looks kinda trash now. For example floated elements came out of position, media screen elements simply didn't work and just loaded the regular large scree elements instead, and 100% width elements seemed to go beyond the viewport (only the ones affected by my javascript?). 
Its important to note that all of these functions worked how intended before removing wpautop.

My question really is; What things does removing wpautop effect? I need to know to diagnose the cause of my formatting chaos. i have checked documentation on wordpress but found nothing that I can see would cause the issue.

Many thanks.

Edit: also, reintroducing the wpautop function did not change anything - so i assume removing it actually removed some php/html code?